# Magento 2: Inline styles for emails are applying partly

Tags: magento2, email, css, frontend, email-templates

For example,
There is a "New order" template. The styles for this template are placed in 
    `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less`

Here's an example of styles:

```
.order-totals {
    background: #e0edf6;

    > tr {
        > th {
            font-weight: @font-weight__regular;
        }

        > th,
        > td {
            padding: @email-content__padding__base;
            text-align: right;
        }

        & + tr {
            th,
            td {
                padding-top: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    .price {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

So, the selectors are all allowed by Magento 2. But actually the only applied styles are:

```
.order-totals{background: #e0edf6}
```

and

```
.price{white-space:nowrap}
```

When emails were being tested in the developer mode, all styles were applied, but now the mode is switched to `production`, css minify is on and styles applied partly. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Magento 2 did not upgrade this library in composer.

**Workaround:**

Update your root composer.json and add this require line :

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "1.2.0 as 0.1.1"
```

Then do a composer update and your mail css should be working.

Moreover, I faced on this issue when I set production mode and not developer mode which enabled minification by default.

Latest Emogrifier release : https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier/releases

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I think this should be reported to Magento development team.
I'll be making more emails in couple weeks and test the latest version.

Comment: There is already a github issue on this topic, and I reported this issue on the Enterprise support.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the answer by myself.

Magento 2 uses [Emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) for parsing the source css and paste it to the email templates. So, if the css is minified by Magento 2, the Emogrifier doesn't seem to work well.
For example, the css code in the question will be minified by Magento 2 the next way:

`.order-totals {background: #e0edf6;}.order-totals>tr>th{font-weight: @font-weight__regular;}.order-totals>tr>th,.order-totals>tr>td{padding: @email-content__padding__base;text-align: right;}.order-totals+tr th,.order-totals+tr td{padding-top: 0;}.price{white-space: nowrap;}`

The problem is that the Emogrifier doesn't "understand" the `.order-totals>tr>th` as a selector, because of spaces absence.

If we write something like: 
`.order-totals > tr > th{font-weight: @font-weight__regular;}`
Parsing go well.

So, if you are using css minify in Magento 2, be sure that the Emogrifier parses your minified css correctly. You can check your css by parsing it online [here](https://www.myintervals.com/emogrifier.php).

In my case, I'm looking for way to not minify only email styles when the Magento 2 css minify is on. If I don't find it, I will have to override every single email template and write the styles inline by myself, which is just not cool at all.

Good luck with customizing email templates in Magento 2, everybody.

Comment: There's a related issue on [Github - Emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier/issues/370)

Comment: @RichJ, yes I've reported this immediately after posting the answer. But my skills are not strong enough to help the Emogrifier devs to investigate this issue. Still, any help on Github will be remarkably useful!

Comment: I've hit the same error which was isolated to `magento/theme-frontend-blank/css/source/_email.less`. Submitted a ticket to be fixed upstream https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10196

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved by updating library `pelago/emogrifier` to lastest version from https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier/releases and also by stopped minifying css file from admin.